# 18.04 Scale up Plymouth splash screen for external monitor on laptop

Tags: boot, plymouth

I use a laptop connected to an external monitor with 18.04, and don't use the laptop screen at all.

It generally works great but the custom splash screen I added with Plymouth shows up when I boot, sized for my laptop screen, not the monitor, and it looks really tacky.

I've spent several hours on this but I don't have the proper knowledge to diagnose the problem.  How can I scale up or resize the splash screen?